# Avoid Ruby open-uri cache

Tags: ruby, caching

I am trying to run a script from my Github Gist page but OpenURI or something else seems to cache it on they way and it never actually updates. I am using the code below on `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Ruby 2.3.1`. I just want it to fetch the script from the url every time instead of using a cached version.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require "open-uri"

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/*/*/raw/*/*.rb"

code_from_url = open(url) {|f| f.read }
eval(code_from_url)
```

Comment: @tadman Obviously i wont post the url to a private gist...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, there was no cache. It was just an incorrect link to a revision specific gist. The correct way to get the latest version of the first file in a gist is `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/{username}/{gist}/raw`

Comment: Try not to use cryptic abbreviations like "Nvm" which are opaque to non-native English speakers and confuse automatic translation programs.